# install Qgifer on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

I tried using PPA but the PPA is old and not working

so tried installing **.deb** package but getting error :

```
$ sudo dpkg -i qgifer_0.2.1-1_i686.deb 
(Reading database ... 194521 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack qgifer_0.2.1-1_i686.deb ...
Unpacking qgifer:i386 (1.1.1) over (1.1.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgifer:i386:
 qgifer:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.1.3).
 qgifer:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~).
 qgifer:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 qgifer:i386 depends on libgif4 (>= 4.1.4).
 qgifer:i386 depends on libopencv-core2.3 | libopencv-core2.4.
 qgifer:i386 depends on libopencv-highgui2.3 | libopencv-highgui2.4.
 qgifer:i386 depends on libopencv-imgproc2.3 | libopencv-imgproc2.4.
 qgifer:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1).
 qgifer:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.6.1).
 qgifer:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1).

dpkg: error processing package qgifer:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgifer:i386
```

So how can install **Qfiger** on ubuntu 16.04.

if not possible please suggest Other .Gif creater/editor software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Initial problem: Installation of QGIFer**

QGIFer cannot be installed on 16.04, as it requires packages that are not co-install-able.  The dependancies cannot be resolved on any version of Ubuntu after 14.04 (Trusty).  This includes installing from source.

I have tested both the .deb installation, an compilation from source.  The dependencies are not available on 16.04.

There is no method to work around this.

Development on QGIFer ceased in 2013, then 14.04 was the predominant LTS release.

Potentially, you could install 14.04 in a Virtual Machine, and work with it that way.  14.04 is still officially supported by Canonical at the time of writing.

It MAY be possible to install the Windows version of QGIFer in Wine, but I think that is out of scope for this question, and may require a question of it's own.

**Alternative Software**

There are many options, but there are no other known applications that will do exactly what QGIFer did.  Here is a non-comprehensive list of applications found with a cursory Search:

- [GIFy](http://giphy.com/create/gifmaker)

An online tool, that will allow you to upload a video and edit; add titles; add overlays etc.

- [EZGIF](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif)

Another online tool, that is more simple.  Upload the video, output a GIF.

- [IMGFlip](https://imgflip.com/gifgenerator)

Just like EZGIF: upload a video, get a GIF.

- [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)

Not capable of importing video on its own, but capable of outputting Animated GIF images. There is a brief tutorial [here](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/)

Comment: Ah, that's a nuisance. I might end up using a virtual machine of older Ubuntu. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can compile it from source, but you will need to install older version of libgif-dev. QGIFer seems to be abandoned for 3 years and not compatible with libgif>4.X
If you don't have it installed as requirement for anything else, you can proceed.

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get remove libgif-dev
sudo apt-get install cmake libopencv-dev libqt4-dev
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/159902387/libgif4_4.1.6-11_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgif4_4.1.6-11_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/159902388/libgif-dev_4.1.6-11_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgif-dev_4.1.6-11_amd64.deb
```

Get the source code:

```
mkdir ~/qgifer && cd ~/qgifer
wget https://github.com/EdzeronK/QGifer/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd Q*
```

Compile:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/" -DQUIET_MODE=ON
make
sudo make install
```

Run:

```
qgifer
```

[image]